# Rated drain to source voltage of a power MOSFET sustaining back EMF of solenoid

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, flyback, powermosfet, back-emf

I have an H-bridge that is using 4 n-channel MOSFETs with max rating of 500 V 100 A drain to source driving a large inductor/actuator reliably. I'd like to find a cheaper MOSFET since the 100 A is overkill. Normal driving operation is 250 V but the back EMF on the inductor has reached >400 V measured on oscilloscope. Can I use a 300 V rated MOSFET since it's just the back EMF and the body diodes will be able to handle the back EMF spike?

EDIT:
CONSIDERING USING MOSFET: FDA59N30

Comment: Do you have the name of those MOSFET-s you use & considering? What is the electrical spec of the "large inductor/actuator"?

Comment: CONSIDERING USING MOSFET: FDA59N30

Comment: It sounds like you are working with .. (forgot the word).., you are doing R&D, in good terms, so spec comes from yourself. FDA59N30 datasheet says "Absolute Maximum Ratings: VDSS Drain-Source Voltage 300 V". 400 V is not healthy environment for that FET working condition, likely kill it at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are working with .. (forgot the word).., you are doing R&D, in good terms, so spec comes from yourself. FDA59N30 datasheet says "Absolute Maximum Ratings: VDSS Drain-Source Voltage 300 V". 400 V is not healthy environment for that FET working condition, likely kill it at once. - jay

yeah this is a bad idea, thanks